# Change date format in php from string format to another in PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to change date format in php from 1/11/2020 (String format) to 2020-11-01

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

```
<?    
$date = "1/11/2020";   
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date );
$sorted = date("Y-n-d", strtotime($date));
```

If you only need it to be presented that way and not actually changing the date stored, you can try using printf() as well

Answer (score 0):

The one liner:

```
echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y','1/11/2020'))->format('Y/m/d');
```